# Обмен данными между двумя процессами node.js

Tags: linux, node.js, debian

Есть 2 процесса на node.js, один запущен под root-ом, а второй под обычным пользователем, все на одной машине.
Цель: организовать между процессами обмен данными, в стиле:

```
{"method":"reboot", "params":{"timeout":0}}
```

и естественно получить ответ о результате выполнения или какой-либо другой информации.
Сейчас реализовано путем поднятия сокет-сервера и сереализации данных в json. Но пришло время дописать это все, и хотелось бы найти более правильный путь, если он есть.
Спасибо

upd: Машина довольно слабая и не хотелось бы поднить http api для таких целей

Comment: Можно сделать через Unix сокеты

Comment: Где-то было про обмен. Почитать про "обмен данными" между процессами: сокеты, pipe(каналы, именованые каналы), разделяемая память.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через Unix сокет, примеров много, вот один из них

```
var client = net.createConnection("/tmp/mysocket");

client.on("connect", function() {
    ... do something when you connect ...
});

client.on("data", function(data) {
    ... do stuff with the data ...
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас так и сделано уже. Думал может есть какое-то другое решение)

Comment: Если нехочется городить то это лучший вариант, можно из одного модуля запускать другой через Cluster и обмениваться event'ами, но не думаю что разница будет сильно заметная